# How to mask value on JSON and XML using C#?

Tags: c#, json, xml, masking

I'm looking for a configurable value masking/sanitizer for both JSON and XML library on c#.

JSON Configuration:

```
{
  "DefaultMaskValue": "#",
  "ConfigurationValue": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "XmlMask": {
        "MaskValue": "#",
        "IsFullMasking": false,
        "Sensitivity": [
          {
            "TargetProperties": [
              "number",
            ],
            "Positions": {
              "Left": 3,
              "Center": 3,
              "Right": 3
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "JsonMask": {
        "MaskValue": "#",
        "IsFullMasking": false,
        "Sensitivity": [
          {
            "TargetProperties": [
              "number",
            ],
            "Positions": {
              "Left": 3,
              "Center": 3,
              "Right": 3
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Result:
XXX456789012345 , 12345678901XXX , 12345XXX9012345

Answer (score 1):

NuGet Library: [JSanitizer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JSanitizer/)

Configurable masking/sanitizer for XML and JSON through extension method.

With JSON Configuration:
[image]

Through Class Configuration:
[image]

[Medium](https://joever-monceda.medium.com/jsanitizer-nuget-library-5d2cdedb435d)
[GitHub](https://github.com/Ethan0007/JSanitizer)